# Causative-Potential or Causative-Passive

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, potential-form, causation

Does a verbal form like this exist.

I found this sentence while reading.

> 一体どこの誰に、今の**こいつを黙らせられる**っていうのか。
>
> Or should I say, who the hell could be able to silence her.

I think the meaning is this, but こいつを黙らせられる is confusing.
Is it Causative-Passive or Causative-Potential?
I know だまらせる is the causative form of だます and it means

> To make someone silent.

But what does だまらせられる mean in this sentence?

> To be silenced or to be able to make silent?

If it were passive it should have been こいつが黙らせられる, or am I wrong?
But I also know that with potential the construction is the same.

> 僕に林檎が食べられる.

I read that depending on emotional attachment and other factors, at least for the potential form, が and を can be exchanged.

So I have 2 questions.
What form is this? Causative-Passive or Causative-Potential?
Why is を used instead of が?

Comment: を is always used for the direct object of a sentence; so if you feel that を is used instead of が; you should always consider the possibility that you don't know how a particular verb works.

Comment: What about verbs like 分かる or Adjectives like 好き, 恨めしい?

Comment: The notion of what word should be the object of a verb and what should be the subject differs between languages, and between verbs.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, だまらせる is the causative form of だまる. And I think this sentence is Causative-Potential. And こいつが黙らせられる is also Causative-Potential in this sentence.

I think が黙らせられる becomes Causative-Potential or Causative-Passive according to the context.
For example, 私に、彼が黙らせられるかな? ("Can I make him be silent?") is Causative-Potential. 私に彼が黙らせられる ("He is made silent by me") is  Causative-Passive.

が and を are commonly used in potential form, but が is more appreciated than を. For example,　私は本が読める、私は本を読める